# How to customize a specific date field in JSON using GSON API in Java?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a JSON structure like below.

```
{
"email":"abc.def@gmail.com",
"mobile":9911776556,
"customerLanguage":"English",
"sms_flag":1,
"ivr_flag":0,
"dateOfBirth":"19-11-1981",
"dateOfJoining":"08-10-2001"
}
```

Now i want to customize only dateOfBirth field, i have tried below but it changes both dateOfBirth and dateOfJoining.

```
Gson jsonConvertor = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").create();
TestJson userAuthenticationDTO = jsonConvertor.fromJson(request_body, TestJson.class);
```

My TestJson class has below structure.

TestJson -->

```
class TestJson{

   Date dateOfBirth;

   Date dateOfJoining;

  // other fields.....

}
```

TestJson object contains both date field modified ,i want only one to be modified?

Comment: Modified how? What are those fields?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis OP has two fields both of `Date` type (`dateOfBirth , dateOfJoining`), and he want's to change the format of only one field keeping the format of another as it is. Basically OP is looking for changing value per field property

Comment: both are string,received from ajax call from Front end to back end(spring mvc service)..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clean way to do this with gson is to write and register your own `TypeAdapter` which serializes your `TestJson` type in an appropriate manner, ie. one `Date` field one way and the other `Date` field in another.

This

```
Gson jsonConvertor = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").create();
```

sets the formatting for any and all `Date` values.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you need to play around with `keys`.

First Approach can be to `deserialize` into a `java.util.Map`, and then just modify the Java Map as wanted.

or something as below

```
JSONObject object=new JSONObject(myJsonString);
JSONObject childobject=object.getJSONObject("dateOfJoining");

JSONObject modifiedjson=new JSONObject();
modifiedjson.put("value", formatedValue());
```